# How to prevent file functions to access files outside game folder?

Tags: c++, file

I'm making a DLL plugin for a game which modders can use in their mods and I'd like to make a function which deletes a file in particular folder. But I want to restrict users from deleting files outside game folder.

```
alignas(16) char s_strArgTemp[0x4000]; // this is the filepath that modder specifies in the function. I am checking if they specified any file on disk like "C:\\Windows" and also checking for "..//" which points to a directory back.

        if (strstr(s_strArgTemp, ":\\")) 
        { 
            *result = -1;
            return true;
        }
        if (strstr(s_strArgTemp, "..\\"))  
        {
            *result = -1;
            return true; 
        }
        if (strstr(s_strArgTemp, "://"))
        {
            *result = -1;
            return true;
        }
        if (strstr(s_strArgTemp, "..//")) 
        {
            *result = -1;
            return true;
        }
```

Will this code be enough?

Comment: You only have to escape backslashes in literal strings, not forward slashes.

Comment: If I call this function woth forward slashes it works fine. "C://test.txt" accesses test.txt

Comment: what stops them from just calling `remove` directly?

Comment: API doesn't allow it. They use functions I make for them.

Comment: @Garlic2394 That's a tangent but I'm curious how you do that.

Comment: @Garlic2394 What prevents them from directly invoking the Win32 syscall which deletes a file? It's fine if you're just trying to prevent people from shooting themselves in the foot, but this approach is utterly ineffective at securely preventing a DLL from doing evil things to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to sanitize paths is to use absolute paths.

```cpp
#include <memory.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

bool sanitizePath(const char* parent, const char* relPath) {
    char fullPath[MAX_PATH] = "";
    
    if(!GetFullPathNameA(relPath, MAX_PATH, fullPath, nullptr)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if(strstr(fullPath, parent) != fullPath) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly path resolving works in windows (all the edge-cases), but [Windows Environment Path Variables](https://superuser.com/a/217506) could also be a problem.

Because of such edge-cases, the path resolvings that do happen on a system can often be hard to predict (and might also change with future versions of the OS).

Due to that you might want to take the input path that you receive as a string, then ask the OS to do the path resolving to get an absolute path. And then check if the resolved path is within the path in which you want to allow modifications.

Comment: These aren't automatically expanded by the Windows API

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not. A path beginning with `\` or `/` is an absolute path on the current drive, such as `\Windows\system32`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to add this check and I'm good to go?

Comment: @Garlic2394 this just one example of a path you won't pick up.  There are many more examples listed in other answers plus others not mentioned yet (e.g. UNC network paths) .  You really need to give up on the idea of handling all these complexities yourself and instead use either OS or C++ library functionality as suggested in other answers.

Comment: well, UNC paths also start with \